# C# WPF with CefSharp crashes in VirtualBox

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualbox, cefsharp

I am trying to run a simple WPF application (x86) using CefSharp WPF (75.1.141) in VirtualBox Windows 10 x64, but it crashes when I try to render a web browser.
It runs normally on the developer's machine Windows 10 x64 using Visual Studion 2017 WPF compiling in .Net Framework 4.5.2.

I already tried changing Cefsharp version to 71.0.0 but it didn't help. Also I tried cefsharp settings with commandline arguments "disable-gpu", "no-proxy-server", nothing changed.

Here are the MainWindow.xaml.cs code

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Init())
            {
                if (browser == null)
                {
                    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
                    ((ChromiumWebBrowser)browser).IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (s, e2) =>
                    {
                        if (((ChromiumWebBrowser)browser).IsBrowserInitialized)
                        {
                            ((ChromiumWebBrowser)browser).Load(textbox_url.Text);
                        }
                    };
                    gridBrowser.Children.Add(browser);
                }
                else if (((ChromiumWebBrowser)browser).IsBrowserInitialized)
                {
                    ((ChromiumWebBrowser)browser).Load(textbox_url.Text);
                }
            }
        }
        static bool init = false;
        private bool Init()
        {
            if (init) return true;
            //Monitor parent process exit and close subprocesses if parent process exits first
            CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;

            var settings = new CefSettings()
            {
                //By default CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
                CachePath = "cache",
                IgnoreCertificateErrors = true,
            };
            init = Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
            return init;
        }
        ~MainWindow()
        {
            if (browser != null)
            {
                ((ChromiumWebBrowser)browser).Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Event Viewer shows these errors

```
1. Info
```

```
Error container 1258037397975457498, type 1
Event name: APPCRASH
Response: No data
CAB ID: 0

Problem signature:
P1: CefSharpTest.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: a8760476
P4: VBoxDispD3D-x86.dll
P5: 6.0.4.28413
P6: 5c4b57a6
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000fb19
P9: 
P10: 

Included files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERCA7F.tmp.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERCC07.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERCC15.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERCC26.tmp.txt

These files can be found here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_CefSharpTest.exe_87545299969ed877b3362d6ccde2f935ae9a282_7a64911f_0491dc52

Analyze symbol: 
Repeated search for the issue: 0
Report Id: 011981c1-b0ed-4e02-b4fe-0361ef1885de
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed container: 952737448bb5f0a7517572591c7bdeda
```

```
2. Critical
```

```
Application: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Platform version: v4.0.30319
Description. The process was completed due to an unhandled exception..
Exception Details: exception code e0000008, exception address 76570882
```

```
3. Critical
```

```
Name of failed application: CefSharpTest.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0xa8760476
Failed module name: VBoxDispD3D-x86.dll, version: 6.0.4.28413, timestamp: 0x5c4b57a6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Error offset: 0x0000fb19
ID of the failed process: 0x1198
Failed application Launch Time: 0x01d55c59eed8c47d
Bad Application Path: C:\Users\Евгений\Desktop\CefSharpTest\CefSharpTest.exe
Failed module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VBoxDispD3D-x86.dll
Report Id: 011981c1-b0ed-4e02-b4fe-0361ef1885de
Failed Package Full Name: 
Bad Package Application Code:
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680

Comment: Thanks. I translated error keys

Comment: Have you installed visual c++? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/75/NuGet/Readme.txt#L32

Comment: There isn't anything meaningful in the error description you've posted, so start with the basic troubleshooting.

Comment: The dependencies are the same between version 67 and 75.version 67 is old and unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried with installed vc++ (but I wanted without). I finally managed this to work by building with cefsharp version 67.0.0 and copying msvcp140.dll and vcruntime140.dll along with .exe. Thank you for your reply anyway.

Comment: I also tried version 69 and it worked, but all versions above crash with same errors. Here is version 71.0.0 debug.log: `[0827/173353.601:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(537)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: No available renderers. [0827/173353.601:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(952)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type [0827/173353.663:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(537)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute. [0827/173355.538:INFO:CONSOLE(50)]`